# Coding exercise to implement IsApproximatelyEqual in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge

this assignment was given to me within the job application process (well, really not much infos given):

> for our applikation we have to compare very often floating point numbers (double, float). Can you code it?
> `public static boolean isApproximatelyEqual(double first, double second) { return ...; }`

well - that was it ^_^

here is my solution, any review is welcome:

**class FloatingPointNumberComparator:**

```
/**
 * used to compare two floating point numbers (double, float) and check if they are approximately equal
 * <p>
 * Limitiations through IEEE754 makes comparison for very small/very big numbers (+/-1E+/-150) imprecise
 * and thus throw an IllegalArgumentException
 */
public class FloatingPointNumberComparator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FloatingPointNumberComparator.class.getName());
    public static final double DEFAULT_APPROXIMATELY_FACTOR = 0.001;
    private static final double BIG_MAX = 1E150;
    private static final double BIG_MIN = -1E150;
    private static final double SMALL_MAX = 1E-150;
    private static final double SMALL_MIN = -1E-150;
    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "this method is cannot be applied to very %s numbers " +
            "(see IEEE754 (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229))";

    /**
     * compares two float point values for ApproximityEquallity
     *
     * @param first  floating point number
     * @param second floating point number
     * @return true if difference between first and second smaller than 0.1%
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException when first/second out of range (+/-1E+/-150)
     */
    public static boolean isApproximatelyEqual(double first, double second) {
        return isApproximatelyEqual(first, second, DEFAULT_APPROXIMATELY_FACTOR);
    }

    /**
     * compares two float point values for ApproximityEquallity
     *
     * @param first               floating point number
     * @param second              floating point number
     * @param approximatelyFactor factor to determine approximation: for 1% set to 0.01, for 0.1% set to 0.001 and so on...
     * @return true if first minus second smaller than approximation
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException when first/second out of range (+/-1E+/-150)
     */
    public static boolean isApproximatelyEqual(double first, double second, double approximatelyFactor) {
        validateInput(first, second);
        double approximatelyRange = first * approximatelyFactor;
        LOGGER.fine("first :" + first);
        LOGGER.fine("second:" + second);
        LOGGER.fine("range: " + approximatelyRange);
        LOGGER.fine("diff:  " + (first - second));
        return Math.pow((first - second), 2) < Math.pow(approximatelyRange, 2); //absolut values using squares
    }

    private static void validateInput(double first, double second) {
        if ((first > BIG_MAX || first < BIG_MIN) || (second > BIG_MAX || second < BIG_MIN)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(ERROR_MESSAGE, "big"));
        }
        if ((first < SMALL_MAX && first > SMALL_MIN) || (second < SMALL_MAX && second > SMALL_MIN)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(ERROR_MESSAGE, "small"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Tests:**

````
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class FloatingPointNumberComparatorTest
{


    @Test
    public void normalPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        double first = 1; //normal float number
        double second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second) );
    }

    @Test
    public void smallPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        double first = 0.9e-130; //small float number
        double second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second) );
    }

    @Test
    public void bigPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        double first = 0.9E130; //big float number
        double second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second) );
    }

    @Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void tooBigNumberTest(){
        //given
        double first = 0.9E151; //big float number
        double second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second);
    }

    @Test (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void tooSmallNumberTest(){
        //given
        double first = 0.9E-151; //big float number
        double second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second);
    }

    @Test
    public void smallFloatPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        float first = 0.9E-40f; //small float number
        float second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second) );
    }

    @Test
    public void bigFloatPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        float first = 0.9E35f; //big float number
        float second = addPermyriad(first);

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second) );
    }

    @Test
    public void overZeroPermyriadTest(){
        //given
        double first = 0.5;
        double second = -0.4999;

        //when
        double approximatelyFactor = 2;

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second, approximatelyFactor) );
    }

    @Test
    public void bigRangeTest(){
        //given
        double first = 1;
        double second = 10;

        //when
        double approximatelyFactor = 10;

        //then
        assertTrue( FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second, approximatelyFactor) );
    }


    private static double addPermyriad(double base) {
        double permyriad = 0.0001; // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point#Permyriad
        return base + base * permyriad;
    }

    private static float addPermyriad(float base) {
        float permyriad = 0.0001f;
        return base + base * permyriad;
    }


}
```
````

Comment: Take a look at the constants: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html   Perhaps, you could reuse some.

Comment: having a default precision of 0.01% works fine for number < 1e150....  i wish i would know what "approximately" really means...  that is pure assumption here

Comment: Rather than a programming question this looks like a "metaquestion" that seeks to find out if you can identify problems in the specification and clarify them. I.e. ask the questions without which the task cannot be successfully completed. These questions are "what is the input range" and "what does approximate mean in this case". Your answer shows that you can code really well but all that may have been complete waste of company time if all the client *needed* was "Math.abs(first - second) < 0.001"

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen i think you are very right! i think they want to see how i can cope with vague settings - and if that hinders me in bringing a solution that is ok, so far....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advice 1**

```
DEFAULT_APPROXIMATELY_FACTOR
```

Consider:

```
DEFAULT_EPSILON
```

**Advice 2**

Make sure your doubles are not `Double.NaN`:

```
private static void checkNotNaN(double d, String exceptionMessage) {
    if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

**Advice 3**

You could possibly do this:

```
boolean equals(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
    // Routine checks here.
    return Math.abs(a - b) <= epsilon;
}
```

**Summa summarum**

All in all, I thought about this:

```
public final class DoubleCompare {

    private static final double DEFAULT_EPSILON = 0.001;

    public static boolean equals(double a, double b, double epsilon) {
        checkNotNaN(a, "The first double value is NaN.");
        checkNotNaN(b, "The second double value is NaN.");
        checkEpsilon(epsilon);
        return Math.abs(a - b) <= epsilon;
    }

    public static boolean equals(double a, double b) {
        return equals(a, b, 0.0);
    }

    private static void checkEpsilon(double epsilon) {
        checkNotNaN(epsilon, "The epsilon value is NaN.");

        checkNotNegative(
                epsilon, 
                "The epsilon value (" + epsilon + ") is negative.");
    }

    private static void checkNotNaN(double d, String exceptionMessage) {
        if (Double.isNaN(d)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }

    private static void checkNotNegative(double d, String exceptionMessage) {
        if (d < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(exceptionMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like your method `boolean equals(double a, double b, double epsilon)` since i have violated the IOSP principle!

Comment: EPSILON!!!! That is the name for it... oh man, i missed that one ;-)

Comment: NaN Check is not properly handled in my code - that is an open bug, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Should we be special-casing infinities as well as NaNs?

Comment: infinite+/- is already handled: `if ((first > BIG_MAX || first < BIG_MIN) || (second > BIG_MAX || second < BIG_MIN))...`, with `BIG_MAX=1E150` and `BIG_MIN=-1E150`

Answer (score 3):

You may want to test the Exception message as well. like below,
Also I would suggest to have few tests with `assertFalse()` inputs

```
@Test
public void tooBigNumberTest(){
    double first = 0.9E151; //big float number
    double second = addPermyriad(first);

    Exception exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second);
    });

    assertEquals("this method is cannot be applied to very big numbers (see IEEE754 (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229))",exception.getMessage());
}

@Test
public void tooSmallNumberTest(){
    double first = 0.9E-151; //big float number
    double second = addPermyriad(first);

    Exception exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> {
        FloatingPointNumberComparator.isApproximatelyEqual(first, second);
    });

    assertEquals("this method is cannot be applied to very small numbers (see IEEE754 (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8766229))",exception.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: yes, i know i have been a bit lazy on that part - testing the message is a very good hint!! (+1)